# how to get the e-signed document from echosign using echosign api in php?

Tags: php, api, echosign

I am using echosign API in my website to send an agreement document to our clients. Once the client signed a document , the signed document will be mailed to admin and the client. We have to download the signed one manually from our mail or from echosign website. Is it possible to fetch the signed document using echosign API.

Answer (score 1):

Using the REST API, you may use `GET /agreements/{agreementId}/combinedDocument` to retrieve a signed agreement. More documentation on the method can be found [here](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5).

Comment: I use this and asked to provide a password to open the resulting document after I save it to disk.  Any ideas?